# Data manipulation in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame like below:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2020-12-01', periods=5, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID" : ["1", "2", "1", "2", "2"],
                   "category" : ["A", "B", "A", "C", "B"],
                   "status" : ["active", "finished", "active", "finished", "other"],
                   "Date": rng})
```

And I need to create DataFrame and calculate 2 columns:

1. New1 = category of the last agreement with "active" status
2. New2 = category of the last agreement with "finished" status

To be more precision below I give result DataFrame:

[image]

Comment: I think this was asked earlier today...

Comment: Why is ID=1, column New1 a value off D?  In your example code there is no element of `category` with the value of "D".   The last "active" status should align with "A" ... correct?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dataframe is already sorted by date, we want to keep the last row where `"status"=="active"`and the last row where `"status"=="finished"`. We also want to keep the first and second columns only, and we rename category to "New1" for the active status, and to "New2" for the finished status.

```
last_active = df[df.status == "active"].iloc[-1, [0, 1]].rename({"category": "New1"})
last_finished = df[df.status == "finished"].iloc[-1, [0, 1]].rename({"category": "New2"})
```

We got two pandas Series that we want to concatenate side by side, then transpose to have one entry per row :

```
pd.concat([last_active, last_finished], axis=1, sort=False).T
```

Perhaps, you also want to call "reset_index() afterwards, to have a fresh new RangeIndex in your resulting DataFrame.